# C#: Delegates and dynamicInvoke

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

this code:

```
public static class MulticastDelegateExtensions
{
    private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public static void InvokeAllAsync(this MulticastDelegate d, params object[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var x = d.GetInvocationList().ToList();
            Parallel.ForEach(x, (item) => item.DynamicInvoke(args));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.Fatal("Error while InvokeAllAsync... Should not happen!!", e);
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
    protected delegate void PriceUpdated(string exchangeName, string commodityName, string contractDate, PriceStruct data);
    protected event PriceUpdated PriceUpdatedEvent;
    protected void cbPriceUpdate(ref ExchangeStruct data)
    {
        if (PriceUpdatedEvent != null)
            PriceUpdatedEvent.InvokeAllAsync(data.ExchangeName, data.CommodityName, data.ContractDate, pricedetail);
    }
```

occasionally fails with:

TaskSchedulerException: `{"An exception was thrown by a TaskScheduler."}`

```
{"Value to add was out of range.\r\nParameter name: value"}

       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InternalRunSynchronously(TaskScheduler scheduler)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunSynchronously(TaskScheduler scheduler)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IList`1 list, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 body)
       at XXX.Extensions.MulticastDelegateExtensions.InvokeAllAsync(MulticastDelegate d, Object[] args) in C:\XXX\Extensions\MulticastDelegateExtensions.cs:line 20
```

Any ideas why and how to get this stuff threadsafe? Or at least some more detailed error?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the inner exception? The error is likely in one of your event listeners.

> Value to add was out of range

Is a `DateTime.Add()` error.